The method of saving a profile image from Flutter to the server(mysql)?
I make an application that androidstudio(flutter) - vscode(mysql, springboot).
During the development process, communication with the server was successful, and even logging in was successful. However, when attempting to change the profile image in the Android Virtual Device (AVD), the message "Image uploaded successfully" appears, but why isn't the image being saved to the user table on the server?
Future<void> _uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final jwtToken = prefs.getString('jwtToken');
    if (jwtToken != null) {
      try {
        // Read the image file as bytes
        List<int> imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
        // Encode the image bytes to BASE64 string
        String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);

        // Set request headers
        Map<String, String> headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $jwtToken',
        };

        // Send PATCH request with JSON payload
        Uri url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/user/profile-image');
        http.Response response = await http.patch(
          url,
          headers: headers,
          body: jsonEncode({'image': base64Image}),
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final imageUrl = jsonDecode(response.body)['imageUrl'];
          setState(() {
            _imageFile = imageFile;
          });
          print('Image uploaded successfully');
          // Optionally, you can update UI or do other tasks upon successful upload
        } else {
          print('Failed to upload image: ${response.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response.body}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Failed to upload image: $e');
      }
    }
  }

This is flutter code.
  @PatchMapping("/profile-image")
public ResponseEntity<? super PatchProfileImageResponseDto> patchProfileImage(
        @RequestBody @Valid PatchProfileImageRequestDto requestBody,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal String email
){
    ResponseEntity<? super PatchProfileImageResponseDto> response = userService.patchProfileImage(email, requestBody);
    return response;
}

This is Usercontroller code in server.
What is problem??
I tried to use dio and multipartrequest in flutter but it wasn't work in server .
